# Basic steps to install a languge pack or locale in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, installation, locale, language-package

I am trying install a German language pack by following below steps.

app/i18n/splendid/de_de/composer.json

```
{
    "name": "splendidinternet/mage2-locale-de-de",
    "description": "German (Germany) language",
    "license": [
        "OSL-3.0"
    ],
    "require": {
        "magento/framework": "^100.0.0"
    },
    "type": "magento2-language",
    "autoload": {
        "files": [
            "registration.php"
        ]
    }
}
```

app/i18n/splendid/de_de/language.xml

```
<language xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/Language/package.xsd">
    <code>de_DE</code>
    <vendor>splendid</vendor>
    <package>de_de</package>
</language>
```

app/i18n/splendid/de_de/registration.php

```
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::LANGUAGE,
    'splendid_de_de',
    __DIR__
);
```

app/i18n/splendid/de_de/de_DE.csv

```
Filled with translation phrases.
```

Run the below commands.

```
php magento setup:upgrade
php magento setup:static-content:deploy de_DE
php magento i18n:collect-phrases -o "/var/www/m7agento211/app/i18n/splendid/de_de/de_DE.csv" -m
**Got the responce : Dictionary successfully processed.**

php magento i18n:pack -d /var/www/m7agento211/app/i18n/splendid/de_de/de_DE.csv de_de de_DE 
**Got the responce : Successfully saved de_DE language package.**
```

Then i configured

```
Admin -> Stores -> Gonfiguration -> General ->Locale Options
<option value="de_DE">German (Germany)</option>
```

**I browsed lot of question like this but none of them has proper answer.**

**No errors in above steps, But language is not applied in front-end. Can any one help me on where i am doing wrong.**

Comment: Is there the `de_DE` language under `pub/static/frontend/Magento/luma` (for example)?

Comment: yes, once deploy the command, i can see the de_DE in pub/static/frontend/Magento/luma